# Help me make sense of the spectrum for the quantum wave function of an infinitely hard equilateral triangle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve the spectrum for a equilateral Tetrahedron with infinitely hard walls. My first guess is to sum up a infinite amount of separable solutions to match the boundary conditions on the faces and edges of the Tetrahedron. While going through the literature though I begun to doubt this method and found something that simply perplexes me.

[image]

[Source: *Mathematical methods of physics* by J Mathews and RL Walker, Chapter 8].

This is a series solution for a equilateral triangle, but it is summed over all of the quantum numbers. I don't see how you can get a spectrum in terms of $l$ and $m$ with this type of a solution, it is superposition of possible energy levels. How does it make sense of the Eigenvalue being a function of $l$ and $m$ if the wave function is summed over all $l$ and $m$, leaving no $l$ and $m$ in it explicitly? I'm sure there is something very elementary I am missing.

Comment: Does this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/342813/197851 help explain what's going on? There are several useful references, including one which tackles the tetrahedral box.

Comment: That answers another question but not this one. I know I need to exploit the Tetrahedral group to come up with the my solution. Also I doubt it will be separable. But for this 2D triangle I found, how does it make sense of the Eigenvalue being a function of n and m if the wave function is summed over all n and m, leaving no n and m in it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation comes from Mathews and Walker *Mathematical methods of physics*, Chapter 8. However, there are several other formulations of the solution to this problem, given in the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/342813/197851 mentioned in my comment.

The key point is that the summation is *not* a sum over quantum numbers characterizing the states of the equilateral-triangle-shaped well. It is simply a statement that the solutions can, in general, be expressed in this form. If we are lucky, each eigenstate will be a finite sum of terms: we just need to determine the coefficients $a_{lm}$. Symmetry, and the boundary conditions, give some relations between them. In this case, unlike some of the simpler examples in quantum mechanics, there is not a one-to-one correspondence between each pair $(l,m)$ and the eigenstates.

In Table 8-2, Mathews and Walker give some of the low-lying solutions, each expressed as a sum of six of the basic functions (whose coefficients have the same magnitude, but may take $+$ or $-$ signs). For example, the ground state may be written
$$
\Psi_0 \propto \psi_{3,1}-\psi_{3,-1} + \psi_{-3,1}-\psi_{-3,-1}
+ \psi_{0,-2}-\psi_{0,2} .
$$
All the contributing functions $\psi_{lm}$ (the complex exponentials in eqn (8-65) of M&W) in this equation have the same value of $\frac{l^2}{9}+\frac{m^2}{3}$.
Then there are excited states, all doubly degenerate, all defined in a similar way. Assigning quantum numbers to these states looks like little more than "labelling" them. But the reference Li and Blinder [*J Chem Educ,* **64,** 130 (1987)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed064p130) given in the above answer describes another scheme in which we can write the energies as
$$
E_{pq} = (p^2+pq+q^2)E_{10}, \quad q=0,\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \ldots,
\quad p = q+1, q+2, \ldots
$$
where $E_{10}$ is the ground state energy. This may seem a bit more systematic. The values of $p$ and $q$ can be matched up to the symmetries (A$_1$, A$_2$ and E) required by the triangle geometry, and it is possible to relate the corresponding wave functions $\Psi_{pq}^{\text{A}_1}$ etc to trigonometric and complex-exponential functions of $x$ and $y$.